# how do I pass on large datasets across different route requests - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Question might be unclear. here's the explanation. Let's say I've:

Route file:

```
Route::get('testing', 'someController@functionOne');
Route::get('testingtwo', 'someController@functiontwo');
```

Controller file:

```
public function functionOne() {
  $this->data = generateReallyBigArray();
  return redirect('testingtwo');
}
public function funtionTwo() {
  // Here $this->data is lost. obviously 'coz this controller file got reinstantiated for @functionTwo
 return view('someview', ['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

`$this->data` is lost the moment `testingtwo` is hit. How do I pass this data across different route requests? Or if there're other ways of doing it.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
public function functionOne() {
  $this->data = 'somedata';
  return $this->functionTwo();
}
public function funtionTwo() {
  // Here $this->data is lost. obviously 'coz this controller file got reinstantiated for @functionTwo
 // even this doesn't work. Exception: Method get does not exist
 return Route::get('testingtwo', function() {
     return view('someview', ['data' => $this->data]);
 });
}
```

Comment: When you say huge data how huge are we talking about? Megabytes? Gigabytes? Terrabytes? Each case has a completely different answer.

Comment: an array of at least 50 list items

Comment: How big is each list item?

Comment: I know this info has to be stored, but temporarily. how do i leverage session table or redis in this case. i don't wanna go with php sessions

Comment: each list item contains 3 items

Comment: OK let's try this again. How big **in megabytes of memory taken** is each list item.

Comment: about but no more than 1kb

Comment: Then flashing it in the session as suggested by @Sohel0415 should be fine.

Comment: Check out [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache) and configure [redis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redis) if you don't wanna go with php sessions

Comment: btw, does redis leverages client memory or server memory?? sorry for this stupid quesiton

Comment: Redis is installed on server, hence it uses server memory

Comment: then i guess it would be a bad idea to store temporary data in redis which is specific to user and isn't frequent.. thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) to send data through session -

```
public function functionOne() {
   $this->data = 'somedata';
   return redirect('testingtwo')->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

Or you could [flash()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data) the data for using on next request.

```
$request->session()->flash('data', $this->data);
```

Comment: $this->data isn't some short message, it could be a huge data that has to be displayed. would it be okay to use session to achieve this...

Comment: rather than sending everything, you could send id, then regenerate again

Answer (score 1):

the best way for that is 
traits

```
trait Data{

    public function getData() {
        // .....
    }
}
```

and in your controllers write

```
use Data;
```

you can use traits over controllers 
or 
You can access your controller method like this:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\controllerName')->getDataFunction();
```

This will work, but it's bad in terms of code organisation (remember to use the right namespace for your ControllerName)